# Run the test JS and PHP in parallel via CircleCI

Tags: unit-tests, continuous-integration, phpunit

I use `CircleCI` to run `JS` and `PHP` test (`Protractor/ Phpunit`).

I would like use parallelism to win time, but I don't know configure the parallelism. I activate the parallelism in the circle parameters (2 containers).

My actual circle configuration (circle.yml) :

```
# Depend de app/config/parameters.circle.yml (parametre symfony pour circle) et app/config/apache.circle (configuration d'Apache pour Circle)

# Configuration du serveur
machine:
    php:
        version: 5.4.21
    timezone:
        Europe/Paris
    hosts:
        bluegrey.circle.dev: 127.0.0.1
    
dependencies:
    pre:
        # SauceConnect (Angular)
        - wget https://saucelabs.com/downloads/sc-latest-linux.tar.gz
        - tar -xzf sc-latest-linux.tar.gz
        - ./bin/sc -u johnnyEvo -k xxx:
            background: true
            pwd: sc-*-linux
        # Installation protractor (Angular)
        - npm install -g protractor
        # On active XDebug
        - sed -i 's/^;//' ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv global)/etc/conf.d/xdebug.ini
        - echo "xdebug.max_nesting_level = 250" > ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv global)/etc/conf.d/xdebug.ini
        # Configuration d'Apache
        - cp app/config/apache.circle /etc/apache2/sites-available
        - a2ensite apache.circle
        - sudo service apache2 restart
    override:
        # Composer
        - composer install --prefer-source --no-interaction
    post:
        # Assets
        - app/console assetic:dump
        # Parameters
        - cp app/config/parameters.circle.yml.dist app/config/parameters.yml
        
database:
    pre:
        # Base de données (test)
        - app/console doctrine:database:create --env=test --no-interaction
        - app/console doctrine:schema:update --force --env=test --no-interaction
        # Base de données (prod/ angular)
        - app/console doctrine:database:drop --no-interaction --force
        - app/console doctrine:database:create --no-interaction
        - app/console doctrine:schema:update --force --no-interaction
        # Fixture
        - app/console doctrine:fixture:load --no-interaction
    
    
test:
    pre:
        # Permission pour que Protractor puisse naviguer le site
        - sudo setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx app/cache app/logs app/sessions
        - sudo setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx app/cache app/logs app/sessions
    override:
        - php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/phpunit -c app
        - protractor angutest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26846904/run-phpunit-and-js-test-simultaneous-via-circleci/26847900#26847900)

```
test:
  override:
    - case $CIRCLE_NODE_INDEX in 0) [Your action in first container] ;; 1) [Your action in second container] ;; esac:
        parallel: true
```